# QTreeView remove decoration/expand button for all items

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I want to have my `QTreeView` always expanded all of the items. In that case, all expand button / decoration are unnecessary and I want get rid of them. How can I delete all of them? `setRootIsDecorated` will only delete that buttons on first level...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what I've done in the past for this problem, it's a bit of a hack but it's worked pretty well. In this case `none.png` doesn't exist.

```
treeView->setStyleSheet( "QTreeView::branch {  border-image: url(none.png); }" );
```

Comment: please tell me where I can look up the names of these style sheets, like how did you find out that this decoration thing is called QTreeView::branch? I want to find out what other things' names are, too.

Comment: @Pavel Late but for other readers: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score 8):

See https://forum.qt.io/topic/4767/how-to-get-rid-of-expande-collapse-qtreewidgetitem-indicator

This got rid of the top level ones for me: `self.setRootIsDecorated(False)`.

I didn't try the item polocy mentioned so I'm not sure this answer can be considered complete. If anyone can verify, feel free to edit this with the confirmation. Until then consider this answer an info-share.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.