# How do you disable expansion in QTreeWidget/QTreeView?

Tags: qt

I just want a tree without those arrows that you click on to expand, I want everything to already be expanded and disallow expansion/unexpansion, is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like...

```
/* Expand all items in tree */
tree_view.expandAll(true);

/* Disable interactive expand/collapse */
tree_view.setItemsExpandable(false);
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: I know that, I don't want the arrows that you click on either, I don't want them to be drawn on the form, do you know how to use style sheets to make that arrow white?

Comment: I just found out how to remove those arrows: widgetItem->setChildIndicatorPolicy(QTreeWidgetItem::DontShowIndicator); Now I wonder how to remove those 90 degree angles at left, looks like you can only do it with root...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018974/qtreeview-remove-decoration-expand-button-for-all-items this answers it